# Reihenfolge in einem So-Satz

Tags: sentence-structure

Ich komme mit der Regel `T(emporal) – K(ausal) – M(odal) – L(okal) = T – K – M - L` nicht klar. Wie schreibe ich den folgenden Satz richtig:

> ... So erfordert jede Websocket-Verbindung in einem JEE Application Server einen neuen Thread.

oder

> ... So erfordert jede Websocket-Verbindung einen neuen Thread in einem JEE Application Server.

Ist die T-K-L-M Regel überhaupt anwendbar an dieser Stelle?

Comment: Vergiss diese Regel! Sie ist purer Unsinn.

Comment: @Emanuel: Würde ich so nicht sagen. Du möchtest nach Leipzig fahren, weil du auf die Buchmesse möchtest. Das ganze am Sonntag. Ohne weitere Betonung wäre das doch »Ich fahre am Sonntag wegen der Buchmesse nach Leipzig«, also TKL. Jede andere Reihenfolge würde meines erachtens das vorne stehende Glied ein wenig mehr betonen, wodurch die Gleichwertigkeit aufgehoben wäre: »Ich fahre nach Leipzig wegen der Buchmesse am Sonntag«. In dem Sinne heißt es nicht, wie im Englischen, dass es *nur so geht*, sondern dass diese Reihenfolge eine »neutrale« ist. Modal hab ich nicht sinnvoll einbringen können.

Comment: @Jan... es gibt Beispiele, da funktioniert es, aber ich kann dir millionen Gegenbeispiele sagen. Eine Regel mit Millionen von Ausnahmen verdient den Namen nicht (und ich bin DaF-Lehrer und habe einige Erfahrung mit diesem Thema)

Comment: @Emanuel: Dann nenn doch gleich ein paar von den Millionen Ausnahmen …?

Comment: @Jan... "Ich fahre dort jeden Tag mit dem Fahrrad hin." "So wird das Wetter in Deutschland diesen Sommer." "Ich wohne hier seit 3 Tagen allein."

Comment: @Emanuel »Ich fahre jeden Tag mit dem Fahrrad dorthin«, »Das Wetter wird diesen Sommer in Deutschland so« (oder wenn du auf vorgestelltem 
*so* bestehst: »So wird das Wetter diesen Sommer in Deutschland«) »Ich wohne seit drei Tagen alleine hier« funktionieren aber alle, oder täusche ich mich?

Comment: @Jan... es geht nicht darum, dass TKM nicht funktioniert. Es geht darum, dass alles andere auch oft funktioniert. Ich kann auch eine MKT-Regel machen. Die ist genauso valide. Studenten denken bei Regel aber, dass das das einzig richtige ist. Sonst würden Fragen wie diese hier garnicht gestellt.

Comment: @Emanuel Ach so hast du das gemeint. Ich hab die Regel als Faustregel verstanden, die direkt mit dem Hinweis »das ist aber nur eine Hilfestellung, alles andere ist auch möglich!« geliefert wird, und dich so, dass es Fälle gibt, wo die Regel *nicht* zu sinnvollen Ergebnissen führt. Gerade Studenten hätte ich als gebildet genug eingeschätzt, dass sie das begreifen …

Comment: @Jan... nee, Studenten wollen bei sowas immer eine Regel, die sie wie eine Maschine einfach anwenden können und dann ist alles richtig. Und alles andere ist dann falsch/komisch. Es gibt übrigens auch Beispiele wo TKM wirklich komische Sätze produziert "Die Sonne scheint in Berlin im Durchschnitt 3 Stunden."... wenn du das umdrehst, dann klingt das so als würde die Sonne danach woanders hingehen. Ist nicht falsch, aber einfach nicht die natürliche Reihenfolge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es ist nicht zwingend klar, was du sagen willst. Es kann sein, dass die Präposition *in* falsch ist und es *zu* sein müsste. Ich vereinfache den Satz aber erst einmal:

> So erfordert jede Verbindung in einem Server einen neuen Thread.
>   So erfordert jede Verbindung einen neuen Thread in einem Server.

Das Problem mit der Präposition *in* im ersten Satz ist, dass die Verbindung nicht zwischen Client und Server liegt, sondern im Server. Der erste Satz besagt hier, dass jede Verbindung, die in einem Server liegt, einen neuen Thread benötigt.
Der zweite Satz besagt, dass für eine jede Verbindung es notwendig ist, einen neuen Thread im Server zu erzeugen.

Also entweder liegt die Verbindung im Server, oder ein Thread wird im Server erzeugt. Letzteres würde noch Sinn machen, Ersteres ist aber Unsinn.

Mit der Präposition *zu* sieht es wie folgt aus:

> So erfordert jede Verbindung zu einem Server einen neuen Thread.
>   So erfordert jede Verbindung einen neuen Thread zu einem Server.

Der erste Satz besagt, dass für eine jede Verbindung, die zu einem Server aufgebaut wird, ein neuer Thread erforderlich ist (im Client). Sprich: Erzeuge einen neuen Thread, um anschließend eine Verbindung zum Server aufzubauen.
Der zweite Satz ergibt nun keinen Sinn mehr, weil dieser besagt, dass eine jede Verbindung "einen Thread zum Server erfordert". Du baust aber keinen Thread zum Server auf, sondern eben eine Verbindung.

Die spannende Frage ist nun, wo der Thread erzeugt werden soll. Im Server oder im Client?

> So erfordert jede Verbindung einen neuen Thread in einem Server. (im Server)
>   So erfordert jede Verbindung zu einem Server einen neuen Thread. (im Client)

Bezüglich der Reihenfolge: Die Präposition hat eine starke Bindung zum vorhergehenden Teil, es ist sozusagen eine Präzision des vorhergehenden Teils.

> Ein Thread wird benötigt. Wo? Ein Thread in einem Server.
>   Ein Verbindung benötigt einen Thread. Welche Verbindung? Eine Verbindung zu einem Server.

In einem ersten Schritt finden wir erstmal Subjekt und Objekt. Im Folgenden in Klammern [] gesetzt:

> So erfordert [jede Verbindung] [einen neuen Thread].

<sup>*Verbindung* ist das Subjekt. *Thread* ist das Objekt.</sup>

Und nun musst du die Präpositionalphrase an das Subjekt *(Verbindung)* oder an das Objekt *(Thread)* anhängen. In den folgenden Beispielen habe ich das Subjekt und das Objekt samt zugehöriger Präpositionalphrase in Klammern [] gesetzt:

> So erfordert [jede Verbindung zu einem Server] [einen neuen Thread].
>   So erfordert [jede Verbindung] [einen neuen Thread in einem Server].

Letztlich geht auch Folgendes:

> So erfordert [jede Verbindung zu einem Server] [einen neuen Thread in einem Server].

Welcher Satz nun richtig ist, musst du entscheiden. ;)

---

Stark vereinfachen kann man es sich, indem man den Satzbau umstellt:

> Jede Verbindung (zu einem Server) erfordert einen neuen Thread (im Server/Client).